# Creating MvxImageView programatically and attaching URI to ImageUrl returns NullPointerException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have custom view which extends `Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager` and has one property `List<Uri> _productImages;` As soon as  _productImages is set through MvxBind and not null, I create an adapter (which extends `PagerAdapter`) and attach it to my custom ViewPager.

In my adapter:

```
public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem (ViewGroup p0, int p1){

  MvxImageView view = new MvxImageView (Context, null);
  view.ImageUrl = Images [p1].AbsoluteUri;

  view.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent);

  return view;
}
```

Line with `view.ImageUrl = Images [p1].AbsoluteUri;` returns NullPointerException (view.ImageUrl is null). As we can see in [MvxImageView](https://github.com/MvxMod/MvxMod/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxImageView.cs)  `_imageHelper` seems to be the problem source. But how can it be null when i'm creating MvxImageView with constructor `public MvxImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs): base(context, attrs)` which initialises `_imageHelper` ?

Comment: note - the code you linked to is in some MvxMod repo - presumably from someone's modified source. The correct repo is slodge/mvvmcross, although it will 'soon' be mvvmcross/mvvmcross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for MvxImageView can trace a warning - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxImageView.cs

Are you loading the download cache and file plugins? (And json if required) For some more info, see:

- Kittens - N=2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ZKgO8fTw4
- Books - N=6 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He6QvnLsPUA